# Set router link for select list in vue js2.0

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to set for select drop down list

```html
<select name="educationOption" class="form-control">
          <option>
            Search for SSC Course
          </option>
          <option v-link="'/higherEducationDetails/'+ user_id">
              Search for Higher Education
          </option>
</select>
```

I tried this also, but not working

```html
 <select name="educationOption" class="form-control">
          <option>
            Search for SSC Course
          </option>
          <option>
            <router-link :to="'/higherEducationDetails/'+ $route.params.id">
              Search for Higher Education
            </router-link>
          </option>
        </select>
```

Any suggestion

Comment: Do you want to navigate users to selected link from drop down?

Comment: yes..user_id will be dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Edit :

`router-link` by default is not gonna work inside select tags however we can do some trick for example:

we can define a normal option tag :

```
<option>
   educationOption
</option>
```

and add event listener on change select value:

```
 <select name="educationOption" class="form-control" v-on:change="changeRoute">
```

and then add changeRoute method to our vue:

```
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                id: 1
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeRout() {
                this.$router.push({path:'/educationOption/' + this.id })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes i have set same route for that as below
{path: '/higherEducationDetails/:id', component: require('./views/institutedetails/higherEducationDetails.vue')},
but its not apply for <option>tag, If i use Button instead of option it works>
but i want it on option change

Comment: Please if this answer solves your problem accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve could be done like this.

```js
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes 
})

const app = new Vue({
  router,
 data: {
    selected: ''
  },
  methods:{
   changeRoute(event){
     const path = event.target.value;
      this.$router.push({ path: `/${path}` });
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
 <select v-model="selected" @change=changeRoute($event)>
  <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
  <option value='foo'>Foo</option>
  <option value='bar'>Bar</option>
</select>
<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Doing something like this should also work for your application.

Answer (score 0):

### I have a trick if you have many pages.

**Enter this into your template**

```
<select id="jenis-transaksi" v-on:change="changeLink">
    <option v-for="option in jenislink" v-bind:value="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
```

**Use the method to run it**

```
export default{
/*Data Section
===================*/
data(){return{
    jenislink: [
        {text:'Transaksi Penempatan Deposito', value: '01'},
        {text:'Transaksi Apa Aja', value: '02'},
    ]
}/*END RETURN*/
},/*END DATA*/
methods:{
    // SELECT ON CHANGE //
    changeLink:function(event){
        if(event.target.value == '01'){
            this.$router.push({path: '/administrasi/transaction' })
        }
        else if (event.target.value == '02'){
            this.$router.push({path: '/administrasi/upload' })
        }
    },

},/*END METHODS*/
}/*export default =-=-=-=-=-=*/
```

I hope you can understand this, so in conclusion we will go to the link from the value option using that method.

### How do you want selected to follow your page?

**Enter this into your template**

```
<select id="jenis-transaksi" v-on:change="changeLink">
    <option v-for="option in jenislink" v-bind:value="option.value" :selected="option.location == link ? true : false">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
```

**Use the method to run it**

```
export default{
/*Data Section
===================*/
data(){return{
    jenislink: [
        {text:'Transaksi Penempatan Deposito', value: '01', location: 'administrasi/transaction/penempatan'},
        {text:'Transaksi Break Deposit', value: '02', location: 'administrasi/transaction/break'},
        {text:'Transaksi Pembatalan Deposito', value: '03', location: 'administrasi/transaction/pembatalan'},
    ]
}/*END RETURN*/
},/*END DATA*/
/*METHODS
===========*/
methods:{
    // SELECT ON CHANGE //
    changeLink:function(event){
        if(event.target.value == '01'){
            this.$router.push({path: '/administrasi/transaction/penempatan' })
        }
        else if (event.target.value == '02'){
            this.$router.push({path: '/administrasi/transaction/break' })
        }
        else if (event.target.value == '03'){
            this.$router.push({path: '/administrasi/upload' })
        }
    },

},/*END METHODS*/
/*COMPUTED
==========*/
computed:{
    link: function () {
        var link = this.$route.path.toString().split('/');
        return link[1]+'/'+link[2]+'/'+link[3]; 
    },
},/*END COMPUTED*/
}/*export default =-=-=-=-=-=*/
```

**You can test the contents of the "link" variable by typing {{link}} your template**